# How to change the showing section with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

i am trying to develop a "dashboard" style website, using php, javascript, html and css. After i made the sidebar, i am trying to change the "page", like, the user is in the home page, after he clicks in any icon of the sidebar, he would change the section (it was hidden, now it is show, for example), without changing the page. I am using a script that i used in another website that i made, but can't figure it out to work in this project, i don't know if it is because i am using php (in the other project, i didn't), or i am messing up the code. If anyone can help, i would appreciate ;)

```js
!(function($) {
    "use strict";
  
    // Nav Menu
    $(document).on('click', '.nav-menu a, .mobile-nav a', function(e) {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var hash = this.hash;
        var target = $(hash);
        if (target.length) {
          e.preventDefault();
  
          if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu, .mobile-nav').length) {
            $('.nav-menu .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
          }
  
          if (hash == '#home') {
            $('#home').removeClass('home-top');
            $("section").removeClass('section-show');
            if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
              $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
              $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
              $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
            }
            return;
          }
  
          if (!$('#home').hasClass('home-top')) {
            $('#home').addClass('home-top');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("section").removeClass('section-show');
              $(hash).addClass('section-show');
  
            }, 350);
          } else {
            $("section").removeClass('section-show');
            $(hash).addClass('section-show');
          }
  
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
          }, 350);
  
          if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
            $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
            $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
            $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
          }
  
          return false;
  
        }
      }
    });
  
    // Activate/show sections on load with hash links
    if (window.location.hash) {
      var initial_nav = window.location.hash;
      if ($(initial_nav).length) {
        $('#home').addClass('home-top');
        $('.nav-menu .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav-menu, .mobile-nav').find('a[href="' + initial_nav + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("section").removeClass('section-show');
          $(initial_nav).addClass('section-show');
        }, 350);
      }
    }
  
    // Mobile Navigation
    if ($('.nav-menu').length) {
      var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
        class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
      });
      $('body').append($mobile_nav);
      $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="icofont-navigation-menu"></i></button>');
      $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');
  
      $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
        $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
        $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
        $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
      });
  
      $(document).click(function(e) {
        var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
          if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
            $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
            $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
            $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
          }
        }
      });
    } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
      $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

body {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
}

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    background: #0f0f0f;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .sidebar.open{
    width: 250px;
  }
  .sidebar .logo-details{
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar .logo-details .icon{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
  .sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name{
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .sidebar .logo-details #btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .sidebar.open .logo-details #btn{
    text-align: right;
  }
  .sidebar i{
    color: #fff;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar .nav-list{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar li{
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .sidebar li .tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: calc(100% + 15px);
    z-index: 3;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0s;
  }
  .sidebar li:hover .tooltip{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .sidebar.open li .tooltip{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar input{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    outline: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #0f0f0f;
  }
  .sidebar.open input{
    padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar .bx-search{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 22px;
    background: #0f0f0f;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .sidebar.open .bx-search:hover{
    background: #0f0f0f;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .sidebar .bx-search:hover{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #2d2d2d;
  }
  .sidebar li a{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    background: #0f0f0f;
  }
  .sidebar li a:hover{
    background: #FFF;
  }
  .sidebar li a .links_name{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .sidebar.open li a .links_name{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  .sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
  .sidebar li a:hover i{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: #11101D;
  }
  .sidebar li i{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  .sidebar li.profile{
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    width: 78px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -8px;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    background: #0f0f0f;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .sidebar.open li.profile{
    width: 250px;
  }
  .sidebar li .profile-details{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .sidebar li img{
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .sidebar li.profile .name,
  .sidebar li.profile .job{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .sidebar li.profile .job{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .sidebar .profile #log_out{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: #0f0f0f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .sidebar.open .profile #log_out{
    width: 50px;
    background: none;
    right: 40%;
  }
  .home-section{
    position: relative;
    background: #E4E9F7;
    min-height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .sidebar.open ~ .home-section{
    left: 250px;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
  }
  .home-section .text{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #11101d;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 18px
  }
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .sidebar li .tooltip{
      display: none;
    }
}

  
.main {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

section {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 140px;
  bottom: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
}

section.section-show {
  top: 100px;
  bottom: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/painel.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <title>Prosw Treinamentos</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
        <div class="logo_name">Prosw Cursos</div>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn" ></i>
    </div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
          <i class='bx bx-search' ></i>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#home">
          <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Videos</span>
        </a>
         <span class="tooltip">Videos</span>
      </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#duvidas">
         <i class='bx bx-chat' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Duvidas</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Duvidas</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#tutorial">
         <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Tutorial de uso</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Tutorial</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#settings">
         <i class='bx bx-cog' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Configurações</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
     </li>
     <li class="profile">
         <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out" ></i>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

    <div class="main">

        <section id="home" class="home-top">
          <div class="content">
            <header>
              <h1>Treinamentos</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="duvidas">
          <div class="content">
            <header>
                <h1>Dúvidas</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="tutorial">
          <div class="content">
            <header>
                <h1>Tutorial</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="settings">
          <div class="content">
            <header>
                <h1>Configurações</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
        </section>

    </div>

<script>
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    menuBtnChange();//calling the function(optional)
  });

  searchBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
  });

  // following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
  function menuBtnChange() {
   if(sidebar.classList.contains("open")){
     closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right");//replacing the iocns class
   }else {
     closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right","bx-menu");//replacing the iocns class
   }
  }
</script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not loading the jQuery library.

Comment: **Always check the browser console for errors** - such as `$ is not defined` - do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added the jquery library
add this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```